# How to set the decimal places of a number in Kendo UI model defenition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox, editablegrid

I'm using a kendo ui editable grid with `NumericTextBox`. Usually in `NumericTextBox` the decimal places are limited to two i.e, if I enter 10.135 the value will be formatted to 10.14. But what I need is to get 10.135 itself. What is to be done here.

My model definition.

```
var GridViewModel = new kendo.data.Model.define({
    fields: {
        Name: { type: "string", editable: false },
        Weight: { type: "number", editable: true, validation: { required: true } },
    }
});
```

and in my view model I have set the Grid as.

```
$("#DryingBinItemsAddedGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
             data: DataDetails,
             schema: {
                model: GridViewModel 
             },
        },
        editable: true,
        dataBound: function () {

        },
        columns: [
               {
                   field: "Name",
                   title: "Name"
               },
               {
                   field: "Weight",
                   title: "Total Weight"
               }
        ]
   });
```

I have not mentioned my failed attempts in this example. Currently my `Weight` field is a numeric text box with two fields. What is to be done here to make my `Weight` field a NumericTextBox with 3 decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to control the configuration of the NumericTextBox used by the grid as the editor, you need to implement a custom editor, otherwise, the default configuration for the NumericTextBox will be used(which is 2 decimal places).

Try changing your "Weight" column definition to:

```
{
    field: "Weight",
    title: "Total Weight",
    editor: weightEditor
}
```

and add a weightEditor function that implements the custom editor:

```
function weightEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>')
     .appendTo(container)
     .kendoNumericTextBox({
         decimals: 3,
     })
};
```

Demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/uviLO